# invalid operands of types 'const char*' and 'const char [93]' to binary

Tags: c++, c

```
char b = (char)i;
        char *text = "function make_page("+b+"){"
"var url = 'http://www.gigasena.com.br/loterias/mega-sena/resultados/resultado-mega-sena-'+"+b+"+'.htm';"
"var page = require('webpage').create();"
"var fs = require('fs');"
"page.open(url, function () {"
    "page.evaluate(function(){"
""
    "});"
    "page.render('results/export-'+"+b+"+'.png');"
    "fs.write('results/'+"+b+"+'.html', page.content, 'w');"
    "phantom.exit();"
"});"
"}"
"make_page("+b+");";
```

Comment: You can't add string literals...

Comment: You´re mathematically adding a character to a memory address here (at least you want to). Don´t confuse C or C++ with eg. Java, and decide for one language (C "or" C++), then we can show you something correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot add string literals in C++.  If you use a [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) object then you can do:

```
int i = 'a';
char b = (char)i;
std::string text = std::string("function make_page(") + b + "){"
    "var url = 'http://www.gigasena.com.br/loterias/mega-sena/resultados/resultado-mega-sena-'+" + b + "+'.htm';"
    "var page = require('webpage').create();"
    "var fs = require('fs');"
    "page.open(url, function () {"
    "page.evaluate(function(){"
    ""
    "});"
    "page.render('results/export-'+" + b + "+'.png');"
    "fs.write('results/'+" + b + "+'.html', page.content, 'w');"
    "phantom.exit();"
    "});"
    "}"
    "make_page(" + b + ");";
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use operator+ on two c strings. You can use this:

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcat

Or you can do something like this:

```
char b;
std::string text = std::string("your text here") + b + std::string("more text etc");
//then use text.c_str() if you need const char*
```