# C++ Move file Char Issue

Tags: c++

```
  int result;
  char old[]="/home/aakash/Downloads/10_Test_Iterations/10 Test Iterations/test";
  char oldname[] ="/home/aakash/memphys/memphys-main/examples/navier_stokes_2D/test"+((char)n)+"_polydeg_3_fields_gmsh.csv";
  char newname[] =old+((char)n)+"/_polydeg_3_fields_gmsh.csv";
  result= rename( oldname , newname );
```

This is my code, I'm basically trying to move files around directories in c++. But whenever I run my code it throws this error:

```
error: invalid operands of types ‘char*’ and ‘const char [5]’ to binary ‘operator+’
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: You can't just add pointers. What you want is string concatenation. Instead of `char` arrays, use `std::string`. Don't make your life harder than it needs to be.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Assign a string literal to a char\*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8356223/assign-a-string-literal-to-a-char)

Comment: @ChrisMM The variables are arrays here, not `char*`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [invalid operands of types 'const char\*' and 'const char \[93\]' to binary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30627073/invalid-operands-of-types-const-char-and-const-char-93-to-binary) or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23936246/error-invalid-operands-of-types-const-char-35-and-const-char-2-to-binar

Comment: @user17732522, you're right. Grabbed the wrong dup

Comment: Aakash, did the answer help? Please ask if you need clarification.

Answer (score 3):

> `char oldname[] ="/home/aakash/memphys/memphys-main/examples/navier_stokes_2D/test"+((char)n)+"_polydeg_3_fields_gmsh.csv";`

You can't concatenate string literals like that. You *could* use `std::strcat` for that but it's easier and less error prone to use the [`string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string) and [`filesystem`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem) libraries:

```cpp
#include <filesystem>
#include <string>

// ...
std::string old =     "/home/aakash/Downloads/10_Test_Iterations/10 Test Iterations/test";
std::string oldname = "/home/aakash/memphys/memphys-main/examples/navier_stokes_2D/test" +
    std::to_string(n) + "_polydeg_3_fields_gmsh.csv";
std::string newname = old + std::to_string(n) +
    "/_polydeg_3_fields_gmsh.csv";
std::filesystem::rename(oldname, newname);
```